# RegEx to find specific number in CSV

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

A Wordpress theme I am currently working on requires the `attachment.php` theme to show other images from the gallery in a thumbnail. My initial thought was to run a WP_Query using a regular expression to find any post / page which has the Attachment's ID in a shortcode (the image won't ever exist in more than one gallery).

However, RegEx is not my strongest point, and I'm struggling to figure out the regular expression needed to find the post based on the shortcode. For example, consider two posts, each of which contains a `[gallery]` shortcode:

```
Post 1 => [gallery columns="1" ids="1,2,3"]
Post 2 => [gallery ids="89,76"]
```

I want to find `Post 1` when looking for the Attachment ID `1`. The RegEx I have so far is:

```
/\[gallery(.*) ids=\"(THIS_BIT_I_NEED_TO_FIX)/
```

However, I am stuck when it comes to actually looking for the number, since I need to match `1`, but not `100` or `21`. It can also be at the start of the `ids` attribute (i.e. `ids="1,`) or somewhere else in the attribute's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
/\[gallery(.*) ids=.*[^0-9]1[^0-9].*\]/
```

The term `[^0-9]` now either matches a , or a " when the number `1` is present in the list of ids.